# Optimizing my syntax highlighter

Tags: android, optimization, syntax-highlighting

I've decided I have to write my own syntax highlighter. So far it's working but it's realtime (you type, it highlights) and it's slow.

I'll try to explain how it works. Each time the user types something into the EditText it runs the highlighter (via TextWatcher). The highlighter searches through the text until it finds the beginning of a word and then searches until it finds the end of the same word. Once it finds a word it searches through an array of keywords, if it finds a match it sets a spannable at that location. It keeps looping until it reaches the end of the document.

Again, it works so far (just trying out this idea before I continue with this method), but it's so slow. Some times it can take over a second just to go through a few lines. It slows down how fast the text appears in the EditText. - I also set where the highlighter starts after text is entered at the last position where the user typed so it doesnt have to go through the whole doc each time, it helps a little but not much.

Here's the basic of my EditText:

```
public class CodeView extends EditText {
    private int mTxtChangeStart;
    String mStructures[] = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.structures);

    public CodeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);

                ...
        }

    TextWatcher inputTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            syntaxHighlight();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            //Set where we should start highlighting
            mTxtChangeStart = start;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {


        }

    };

    private void syntaxHighlight() {

        //Time how long it takes for debugging
        long syntime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("", "Start Syntax Highlight");


        //Get the position where to start searching for words
        int strt = mTxtChangeStart;

        //Get the editable text
        Editable txt = getText();


        //Back up the starting position to the nearest space
        try {
            for(;;) {
                if(strt <= 0) break;
                char c = txt.charAt(strt);

                if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
                    strt--;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("", "Find start position failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }   

        //Just seeing how long this part took
        long findStartPosTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("", "Find starting position took " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - findStartPosTime) + " milliseconds");

        //the 'end of a word' position
        int fin = strt;

        //Get the total length of the search text
        int totalLength = txt.length();

        //Start finding words
        //This loop is to find the first character of a word
        //It loops until the current character isnt a space, tab, linebreak etc.
        while(fin < totalLength && strt < totalLength) {
            for(;;) {
                //Not sure why I added these two lines - not needed here
                //fin++;
                //if(fin >= totalLength) { break; } //We're at the end of the document

                //Check if there is a space at the first character.
                try {
                    for(;;) { //Loop until we find a useable character
                        char c = txt.charAt(strt);
                          if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r'){
                            strt++; //Go to the next character if there is a space
                          } else {
                            break; //Found a character (not a space, tab or linebreak) - break the loop
                        }
                    }
                }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }

                //Make sure fin isnt less than strt
                if(strt > fin) { fin = strt; }

                //Now we search for the end of the word
                //Loop until we find a space at the end of a word
                try {
                    for(;;) {
                        char c = txt.charAt(fin);
                        if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
                            fin++; //Didn't find whitespace here, keep looking
                        } else {
                            break; //Now we found whitespace, end of a word
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    //If this happens it should mean it just reached the end of the document.
                    Log.e("", "End of doc? : " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }   
            }

            Log.d("", "It took " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - findStartPosTime) + " milliseconds to find a word");

            //Make sure fin isnt less that start, again
            if(strt > fin) { fin = strt; }

            //Debug time, how long it took to find a word
            long matchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            //Found a word, see if it matches a word in our string[]
            try {
                for(String mStruct : mStructures) {
                    if(String.valueOf(txt.subSequence(strt, fin)).equals(mStruct)) {
                        //highlight
                        Spannable s = (Spannable) txt;
                        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), strt, fin, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        //Can someone explain why this is still setting the spannable to the main editable???
                        //It should be set to txt right???

                        break;

                    } else {
                        /*Spannable s = (Spannable) txt;
                        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), strt, fin, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        txt.removeSpan(s);*/
                    }
                }

            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("", "word match error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            //Finally set strt to fin and start again!
            strt = fin;
            Log.d("", "match a word time " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - matchTime) + " milliseconds");
        }//end main while loop

        Log.d("", "Syntax Highlight Finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - syntime) + " milliseconds");
        mTextChanged = false;
    }


}
```

"structures" resource (php.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name="structures">
            <item>if</item>
            <item>else</item>
            <item>else if</item>
            <item>while</item>
            <item>do-while</item>
            <item>for</item>
            <item>foreach</item>
            <item>break</item>
            <item>continue</item>
            <item>switch</item>
            <item>declare</item>
            <item>return</item>
            <item>require</item>
            <item>include</item>
            <item>require_once</item>
            <item>include_once</item>
            <item>goto</item>
        </string-array>

</resources>
```

Anyone have any suggestions how to make this search faster? I know I have a lot of loops but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two hints to get you going: Lexical analysis (what the big dogs use), and regular expressions (essentially what lexical analysis is)

Comment: Since this question is quite localized and basically a request for codereview, I feel like it belongs on codereview.SE and have voted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Can you split the string on the delimiters you have there rather than looking at each character? That would speed it up some. (String.split())